# Problems with modulo when calculating fibonacci

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci, modulo

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to calculate Fibonacci numbers up to 10^18 mod 10^9+7. The online judge is saying that I get right answers on the small cases (where the modulo isn't required), but in larger cases I get wrong answers.

There is no problem with the algorithm otherwise, but the memoization aka saving the results into the dictionary `table` seems to have failed. I have no idea why.

```
luku = int(input())
table = {0:0, 1:1, 2:1}

def fib(num):

    if num in table:
        return table[num];

    if num % 2 == 0:
        puoli = num / 2;
        ans = (fib(puoli) * (2 * (fib(puoli + 1)) - fib(puoli))) % 1000000007;
        table[num] = ans;
        return ans;
    else:
        puoli = (num-1) / 2;
        ans = (fib(puoli + 1)*fib(puoli + 1) + fib(puoli)*fib(puoli)) % 1000000007;
        table[num] = ans;
        return ans;


print(fib(luku))
```

For example, with the input 54774730983471038 I'm getting 946469205 instead of the correct answer 795317107.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with memorizing.

Possibly to your surprise, the problem is that **floating point precision** (yeah, your numbers are truncated).

You should replace floating division operator `/` (single slash) with integer division operator `//` (double).

The following code, with the only fix mentioned above, works for me:

```
luku = int(input())
table = {0:0, 1:1, 2:1}

def fib(num):
    if num in table:
        return table[num];

    if num % 2 == 0:
        puoli = num // 2;
        ans = (fib(puoli) * (2 * (fib(puoli + 1)) - fib(puoli))) % 1000000007;
        table[num] = ans;
        return ans;
    else:
        puoli = (num-1) // 2;
        ans = (fib(puoli + 1)*fib(puoli + 1) + fib(puoli)*fib(puoli)) % 1000000007;
        table[num] = ans;
        return ans;


print(fib(luku))
```

See:

```
ibug@ubuntu:~ $ python3 t.py
54774730983471038
795317107
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. When should I use the integer division sign? When are the numbers too large for the normal division sign?

Comment: the `/` yelds a floating point result, which, unlike an integer result, has finite precision. But it's called _memoizing/memoization_, without the _r_.

Comment: @Quiti Use `//` when you want to perform integer division. The result of `a / b` is always a floating point number, even if both `a` and `b` are integers.

Comment: @WalterTross Oh, huh. That's a new word that I've just learned that it exists!